# Select Minimum START_DATE and Maximum END_DATE from the below data inside a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

"-> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22"

" -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-12-SEP-17-20-SEP-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-07-JUN-17-20-OCT-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-06-APR-12-15-AUG-22"

Above is the same data inside the column.

We need to create a query to select *Min Start Date* and *Max End Date* from this column.

The Dates should not be from CID and Feature Level.
`start_date` and `end_date` are written side by side with the Item Type.

Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE temp1
(
 path_start_date VARCHAR2(1000),
 start_date      DATE,
 end_date        DATE
);

INSERT INTO temp1 (PATH_START_DATE) 
VALUES(' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22');
```

Desired Output :

```
Start_Date = 13-NOV-18
End_Date   = 15-AUG-22
```

these values need to be populated in the start and end date column of the table.

Comment: How the data is stored inside the table? Please post the table structure and your expected output as well

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Added the details. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure that the dates would always be in the format of `FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-start_date-end_date')`

Comment: yes they will be same always :)

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the values are fixed throughout the table, then use

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(path_start_date,'[^>]+',1,level+1) AS piece,
        path_start_date
   FROM temp1
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(path_start_date,'>')  
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR path_start_date = path_start_date 
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(piece,INSTR(piece,'-',1,1)+1,INSTR(piece,'-',1,4)-INSTR(piece,'-',1,1)-1),'DD-MON-RR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS date1,
         TO_DATE(SUBSTR(piece,INSTR(piece,'-',1,4)+1,9),'DD-MON-RR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS date2,
         path_start_date
    FROM t
   WHERE TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(piece,'[^-]+')) NOT IN ('CID','FEATURE') 
)
SELECT path_start_date,MIN(LEAST(date1,date2)) AS "Start_Date", MAX(GREATEST(date1,date2)) AS "End_Date"
  FROM t2 
GROUP BY path_start_date
```

in order to seperate each substrings by `>` character through use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function, and then determine four date values for each *path_start_date* value while eliminating the parts starting with the undesired substrings

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46fb2695850e26bf6339a56f955ed5ef)</kbd>

Comment: Can you write it as a generic query by selecting the 3 columns from the table ??@Barbaros

Comment: thanks you so much for the efforts. It works as expected . I Will work on its performance.